# AngularJS: Watch transcluded content change with interpolation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**I've put together a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hmVEG4FJFEZc530I50Qc) that best illustrates my issue.**

I'm attempting to write a simple directive that will update the transcluded html from a directive.

For example I would like to have:

```
<make-bold>Foo *bar* {{something}}</make-bold>
```

Generate into

```
<span>Foo <b>bar</b> somevalue<span>
```

The example on plunker works fine, but I can't figure out how to get notifications (watch) of the transcluded content changing. In the example, try selecting different items (by clicking on them), and you'll notice "Processed" does not update.

I'm pretty sure the issue is that the element passed to the link function does not update, but it's content updates, thus it can't be watched.

**Directive**

```
app.directive('makeBold', function($interpolate, $timeout, $compile)
{

  var regex = new RegExp("\\*(.+?)\\*", 'g');
  var replace = "<b>$1</b>";

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs)
    {
      scope.$watch(
        function() { 
          // *** What do I need to watch here? ***
          return element;
        }, 
        function(n, o) {
          var text = $interpolate(element.text())(scope); 
          var newContent = text.replace(regex, replace);
          $timeout(function() { element.html(newContent); });
      });

    }
  };
});
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-show="selected">
    <h1>{{selected.name}}</h1>
    <p><i>Original:</i> {{selected.detail}}</p>
    <p><i>Processed:</i> <make-bold>{{selected.detail}}</make-bold></p>
</div>
```

(Note: I don't actually want to make a 'make-bold' directive, but this illustrates the issues I am having.)

Comment: So you want to get the displayed text of your HTML and then re-interpolate it?

Comment: @blesh my conclusion is there is no good way to re-interpolate. If the default interpolation behavior do not fit a use case then a proper way is to disable it and use $interpolate and $watch manually. Internally, the default behavior itself is a directive (addTextInterpolateDirective).

Comment: @blesh, correct. I could get this kind of working if I watched element.text(), but it would fire again after doing the "bold formatting", so the second time around it would end up stripping it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RXwHiqQ9dOnpx9KdJHl3)

This one was not obvious and very challenging. 
I had to look inside angular.js source code to fully understand where transcluded contents live and what angular doing with interpolated text.

The trick here is to disable angular interpolation and use $interpolate manually.

addTextInterpolateDirective function inside [compile.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.7/src/ng/compile.js)
is responsible for the magic binding of interpolation ( {{ }} ).

Later, I will update this answer with detailed explanation.

#### Solution:

```
app.directive('makeBold', function( $interpolate ) {

  var regex = new RegExp("\\*(.+?)\\*", 'g');
  var replace = "<b>$1</b>";

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
      var interpolateFn = $interpolate(tElem.html(), true);
      tElem.empty(); // disable automatic intepolation bindings
      return function(scope, elem, attrs){
        scope.$watch(interpolateFn, function (value) {
          var newContent = value.replace(regex, replace);
          elem.html(newContent);
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I bet you work on a native markdown directive or something similar. If you need more help I will be happy to get involved.

Comment: Do you think we could have a generic directive for both dynamic data from the scope (this case) and just basic static html text?

Comment: you can check `interpolateFn`, if it's null then it's a static text and you don't need to set a watch. check this https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.15/src/ng/compile.js#L1833